# rewrite url (redirection)

Tags: 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to rewrite url:

```
www.domain.com
domain.com
```

to

```
www.domain.com/sell.html
```

Were sell.html is already rewritten I need some kind of redirection.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question. Seems more appropriate for webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.domain.com/sell.html [R=301,L]
```

This will create a 301 (permanently moved) redirect from the root URL (/) to sell.html.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your .htaccess file and put this code there:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.domain.com/sell.html [R=301,L]
```